# WAMPServer updates from WAMPServer Alive project... are they safe?

Tags: windows

I've been using WAMPServer for a fair while and been really happy with it. Unfortunately I've been itching for an Apache 2.2.15 addon for it (currently there's only a 2.2.14 one).

I know that I can 'manually' install an updated version, but I really did appreciate the ease of just installing the addon and having the paths etc. set correctly.

Anyway, in my search, I came across the WAMPServer Alive project at http://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserveralive/ .

My question is pretty basic: does anyone have any experience with addons from this project? Are they safe to use? Is there any reason in particular that I should not trust it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2 addons currently provided should work at least as fine as the official WampServer addons. In fact, some bugs have been fixed :)

HOWEVER, there is an annoying issue with PHP 5.3.2, it is not due to the Wamp addon but to PHP itself. It means if you installed PHP 5.3.2 manually you will encounter the same issue.

It also means a lot of people will probably complain to the Wamp addon author (... me!) despite the fact I have no responsibility in it... So I'll update the readme file with a big WARNING and a detailled explanation of the issue.

Cheers

source : the author

Comment: Hi Double Gras: so are you the person that runs the WAMPServer Alive project itself, or the person that wrote the addon 'subproject'? Or maybe even both? Either way, thanks for keeping the project 'alive'.

Comment: As you can notice on its website, the original WampServer provides some addons, useful for testing different versions of a component, and upgrading Wamp with no need to release a new full version of Wamp. These addons had been existing before I came. Currently, the "Wamp Alive" project (I created) intends to reproduce the logic of these addons in order to bake up-to-date ones. Later I could even consider to implement some changes to WampServer itself ;) However, I'm currently busy and can only dedicate very little time to this project, I hope I could improve that. Cheers